# How to refresh the (live) Datastore Entity browser's `Kind` dropdown menu list?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The Developer Console Datastore Entity browser's `Kind` dropdown menu list doesn't seem to pick up the kinds for the entities newly created by my GAE app:

[image]

I am certain the new entities exist as I can access them in my app as well as in the Entity browser but via Key links from related entities of kinds already included in the dropdown list.

How can I make the Entity browser refresh this `Kind` dropdown list to include recently added entity kinds?

Notes:

- the issue is seen only in production, the `dev_appserver.py`'s browser automatically adjusts the list as the new entities are created
- it doesn't appear to be just a (short) timing issue - the kinds are still missing in the list even a half-hour after the respective entities were created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a full page refresh (Refresh button of the browser). That has been working for me. I noticed that the list refreshes occasionally when the drop-down arrow is clicked, but is not consistent.

Comment: Yep, that did it. I was clicking on the `Refresh` button inside the browser page, assuming it does refreshes the entire page, but apparently it doesn't.